# Recursive function program - find the route that maximizes the sum of values in two dimension arrays

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to find the path in two dimension arrays in order to get the maximal value that is the summation of each value in the path.

For example, here is my two array as below.

6 0 0
1 2 0
6 7 4

Starting at the (0,0) and find the path that has the maximal summation value.
(Path can be directed into only two ways as follows, if a current point is (y,x) then, next path can be (y+1,x) or (y+1,x+1)).

After applying above procedure, the converted dimension arrays will be as follows:

```
6 0 0      15 0 0   
8 9 0  ->  8 9 0  
6 7 4      6 7 4
```

Therefore, the solution is 15. And I tried to make a code using recursive function as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

namespace DIAMONDPATH {
    int dia[2 * 100][100];
    int copy_dia[2 * 100][100];

    int path(int y, int x,int height) {
        if (height == y + 1) {
            return dia[y][x];
        }

        copy_dia[y][x] = max(dia[y][x]+path(y + 1, x,height), dia[y][x]+path(y + 1, x + 1,height));

        cout << "y : "<<y<<" x : "<<x<<" value : "<< copy_dia[y][x] << endl;
    }
    int do_main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
        freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);

        int TC;
        cin >> TC;

        while (TC--) {
            int N;
            cin >> N;

            memset(copy_dia, -1, sizeof(copy_dia));
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
                    cin >> dia[i][j];
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < N ; ++j) {
                    cout << dia[i][j] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }




            int ret = path(0, 0,N);



            cout << endl;

        }
        return 0;
    }
}

#ifndef DRIVER

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return DIAMONDPATH::do_main(argc, argv);
}

#endif
```

However, I ran my codes, the final results (the position of (0,0)) is not the value what I intended. It returned unknown value. I couldn't know where it came from.

As you can see, path function is the getting the maximal value of optimal path in my arrays. and I inputted the 3x3 dimension arrays as below.

6 0 0
1 2 0
6 7 4

I tried to debug using printf but I failed because it was recursive and very hard to understand and see each procedure. Therefore I posted my problems here and would like to know how to debug it and where did the unknown value came from ?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Increase your warning levels and then "warning: control reaches end of non-void function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `path()` doesn't return the value (that is: return an undefined value) when `height != y+1`; suggestion: add a `return` instruction like

```
int path(int y, int x,int height) {
    if (height == y + 1) {
        return dia[y][x];
    }

    copy_dia[y][x] = max(dia[y][x]+path(y + 1, x,height), dia[y][x]+path(y + 1, x + 1,height));

    cout << "y : "<<y<<" x : "<<x<<" value : "<< copy_dia[y][x] << endl;

    return copy_dia[y][x];  //  <-----  add return
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments :D